# SQL Table Design for Reporting

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I am building a platform that allows users to report posts/messages/events/etc. Each of these have their own table with their own id. How do I design a report table that allows users to report any of these things?

One way would be to do this is:

```
CREATE TABLE report (
    report_id INT,
    reported_id INT,
    type VARCHAR(100), ...);
```

where type tells me which table report_id refers to. However, I cannot have a foreign key constraint if I do this.

I could also create a report table for each type, which seems a little messy.

Comment: If you want enforced foreign keys you can opt for two options: 1) Have many fk columns on a single table, or 2) have many tables, each having a single fk column. Otherwise, you can try 3) "weak references", where you don't really have bona fide fks, but just column values you interpret as fks. I tend to prefer option #1.

Comment: Impaler's option 3 is usually a nightmare in the long run. Another option is one reporting table, but a simple separate linking table for each posts/messages/events that pairs their id values with a report's id value.

Comment: Tables in a relational database should model the entity that they represent.  So if a Post is different from a Message is different from an Event, etc. then each of these entities should have its own table.  This allows you to implement referential integrity using FK constraints.  Additionally, as the database grows (because these kinds of things always either grow or go unused) you can expand upon the Messages without affecting Posts or Events adversely.

Comment: Should I consider MySQL inheritance as a solution?